# Does opensource override exist for inputFile with accept attribute?

Tags: jsf

In our project we are using jsf for frontend development. I got the task to filter the shown file in the browser (we already have validation both on server and client side) if they type is not accepted. 
I know that for input tags an accept attribute exist, but in our implementation we use a heavily overwritten inputFile tag, which does not have an accept attribute.

My original idea was, that I rewrite inputFile tag to have an accept attribute, but I could not find any opensource example. Does any exist?

Comment: here is some documentation on how to write custom components: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364786/Building-Custom-JSF-UI-Components

Comment: Thank you! Though I already have a basic grasp how to implement custom components (I had to modify a few), I was hoping to find an opensource version where it is already implemented.

Comment: My main problem mostly is that I am not sure, how will I get the file browser instance, in this case.

Comment: OmniFaces has [one](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/inputFile).